# Can't query within a query

Tags: soql

I'm attempting to run a query within a loop to fetch a record and place the value into a newly created record, but am getting an error when attempting the 2nd query.  I only included a small portion of the class so it's less confusing.For some reason I'm getting an "Unexpected token 'bankAcc.id' error for the query starting with "Onboarding_Bank_Account__c Onbankacc".Anybody have any ideas on this ?

```
 for(Bank_Account__c bankAcc : [Select Id,Status__c,Program_Onboarding__c,Program_Supplier__c,Organization__c FROM Bank_Account__c WHERE Id IN: setProgramBakAccountUpdated]) {

       Onboarding_Bank_Account__c Onbankacc =  [SELECT Program_Bank_Account__c FROM Onboarding_Bank_Account__c WHERE 
Program_Bank_Account__c = bankAcc.id ORDER BY LastModifiedDate ASC NULLS FIRST LIMIT 1] ;

            // Create new Milestone for each Bank Account in the List
            Milestone__c newMilestone  = new Milestone__c();

            //Set Milestone Field Values
            newMilestone.Program_Bank_Account__c = bankAcc.Id;
            newMilestone.Program_Supplier__c = bankAcc.Program_Supplier__c;
            newMilestone.Account_Record__c = bankAcc.Organization__c;
            newMilestone.Organization_for_UI__c = bankAcc.Organization__c;
            newMilestone.Master_Record_Updated__c = true;
            newMilestone.Onboarding__c = Onbankacc.id;
```

Comment: You know `LastModifiedDate` can't be null, right? Also query in a loop = BAD.

Comment: ah yes. I originally was sorting on another custom field. I forgot about that in there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're just missing a binding colon:

```
Onboarding_Bank_Account__c Onbankacc = [
    SELECT Program_Bank_Account__c 
    FROM Onboarding_Bank_Account__c 
    WHERE Program_Bank_Account__c = :bankAcc.id 
    ORDER BY LastModifiedDate ASC NULLS FIRST LIMIT 1
] ;
```

`bankAcc.id` --> `:bankAcc.id`

However, this looks like it can be and should be bulkified by making this query a subquery of your primary `for` query.

Comment: you da man ! Thanks David.